# plpgsql function text concatenation error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can any one correct below statement?

```
strdir := 'copy '
          || t_name.relname
          || ' from E'''' || C: || '''''
          || t_name.relname || '''.txt'' using delimiters '|'';
```

Comment: What is the problem? Just count the quotes. Will be easier with a highlighter, though...

Comment: The Error is LINE 1: ...rom E''''||C:||'''''||  $2 ||'''.txt'' using delimiters '|''

Answer (score 1):

```
strdir := 'copy '
          || t_name.relname
          || ' from E''C:"'  -- one ' to many here, included C:, which had no '
                             -- and I suspect you need a double quote here "
          || t_name.relname
          || '".txt'' using delimiters ''|'''; -- closing ", double ' around |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the single quotes around the last `|` should be two single quotes each.

Comment: I tried that i am getting follwoing error "ERROR:  operator does not exist: text | unknown
LINE 1: ...E''''||C:||'''''||  $2 ||'''.txt'' using delimiters '''|''''"